# iOS Safe Area Sizes Somehow is 88 instead of 44

Tags: ios, autolayout

Why is the `Top Safe Area Inset` is 88? according to the docs it should be 44.
my bet is the navigation bar but its size is 66.
Ant help here would be great!
Thanks

Comment: How are you getting the `safeAreaInset`? Could you please add your code snippet in the question? Also attach the screenshot on which it is `88`.

Comment: Retina display @2x maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In **iPhone-X** default y 44px of safe area and navigation bar height 44px so if you are using iPhone-X & navigation bar so it will be 88px header. and footer height is 34px. finally you will get Safe Area height = 734px (812 - 88 - 34)

In **other Device** default y 20px of safe area and navigation bar height 44px so it will be 64px header.